# Inconsistent vector operations in R?

Tags: r, vector, matrix-multiplication

I teach mathematics and programming (with R) at university and I am a big fan of a good and consistent notation. Please have a look at the following simple vector operations in R:

```
> v1 <- c(1,2,3)
> v2 <- c(4,5,6)
> v1 %*% v2
     [,1]
[1,]   32
> t(v1) %*% v2
     [,1]
[1,]   32
> v1 %*% t(v2)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    4    5    6
[2,]    8   10   12
[3,]   12   15   18
> t(v1) %*% t(v2)
Error in t(v1) %*% t(v2) : non-conformable arguments
> v1 + v2
[1] 5 7 9
> v1 + t(v2)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5    7    9
> t(v1) + t(v2)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5    7    9
```

I think there are some inconsistencies here: Either I am missing something or R seems to be quite arbitrary with respect to what results you get when you either transpose a vector or not.

What is the underlying logic here (which seems to be completely different than Matlab by the way).

Comment: Why have you tagged this with `Matlab`?

Comment: I do agree that Matlab's rules are more consistent.  R tries to do things (promoting vectors to row or column matrices as seems appropriate, dropping dimensions) that are convenient for interactive analysis.  Its behaviour **is** well-defined, as @GavinKelly's answer below points out, but that doesn't mean it's not sometimes confusing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`?%*%` gives the logic:

Multiplies two matrices, if they are conformable.  If one argument
is a vector, it will be promoted to either a row or column matrix
to make the two arguments conformable.  If both are vectors it
will return the inner product (as a matrix).

If they're both vectors (first example), then you get the inner product.  If you put a `t(  )` in there, the vector will get cast as a column matrix, and a vector is  effectively a row matrix, so normable conformable rules apply.

Similarly, the help page for "+" says that it will  cast the arguments to vectors - and gives some guidance on the 'shape' of the result.